# Why do I see different number of packages in /usr/share/doc and when using dpkg -l command?

Tags: linux, debian, packages

```
user@host:~$ dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | wc -l
1212
user@host:~$ ls /usr/share/doc/ | wc -l
1148
```

My goal is to gather license information for all installed packages. Using `dpkg -l` command gives me 1212 records, but I only see 1148 directories under `/usr/share/doc/`. What could explain for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to figure this out: comparison.

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | wc -l
3170
deltik@node51 [~]$ ls /usr/share/doc/ | wc -l
2964
```

Each line of `dpkg -l | tail -n +6` is formatted like this:

```
ii  zram-config                                                 0.5                                                      all          Upstart job to enable zram support
```

Each line of `ls /usr/share/doc/` is formatted like this:

`zram-config`

To get the commands to match each other, they would have to look like `dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | awk '{print $2}' | sort -h` and `ls /usr/share/doc/ | sort -h`.

Now put the outputs into two files:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | awk '{print $2}' | sort -h > /tmp/a.txt
deltik@node51 [~]$ ls /usr/share/doc/ | sort -h > /tmp/b.txt
```

And diff them (use `colordiff` for easier viewing):

```
colordiff /tmp/{a,b}.txt
```

On my system, I saw these patterns:

- If you have two different architectures, you'll see that `/usr/share/doc/` only shows the base package without the architecture added:

  ```
  305,308c305,306
  < gcc-5-base:amd64
  < gcc-5-base:i386
  < gcc-6-base:amd64
  < gcc-6-base:i386
  ---
  > gcc-5-base
  > gcc-6-base
  ```

  This accounts for most of the difference on my multiarch (`i386` and `amd64`) system.
- If you ignore the different architectures from the `dpkg -l` command (`dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}' | sort -h | uniq > /tmp/a.txt`), you'll see that some packages don't put anything in `/usr/share/doc/`, like packages that begin with `linux-image`.
- Or there is a different name of folder in `/usr/share/doc/`, like `NetworkManager` for the `network-manager` package or `HTML` for various KDE packages.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common reasons for this:

1. Not all packages contain actual data.  Some are so-called 'metapackages', which consist solely of a list of dependencies (the main packages for most desktop environments are good examples).  Some are 'virtual' packages, which exist to provide an easy way to depend on a particular service without caring which implementation is used (the 'init' package on Debian is one such example).  Debian also has 'transitional dummy packages' which exist to make sure dependencies still resolve correctly during upgrades (because dpkg itself has no way of renaming installed packages).
2. You may have some packages that were removed, but still have configuration files present on the system.  The `dpkg` command you gave will still list these packages alongside ones which are installed, but they will almost never have a directory under `/usr/share/doc`.